# How to open React component as new page from a button in different component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm brand new to React and having troubles with the routing. I want to open a component as a new page when a button/link is clicked rather than the component loading under the component containing the button/link.

Component with link segment (experience.js):

```html
<div className="experience-desc-wrapper">
  <p> filler text </p>
  <Router>
    <Link to="/classlist">Click this link to see relevant coursework</Link>
    <Route exact path="/classlist" component={ClassList}/>
  </Router>
  </p>
</div>
```

Component I want to open in a new page (classlist.js):

```js
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';

class ClassList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      hello!
      <
      br / >
      test 1 <
      br / >
      test 2 <
      /div>
    )
  }
}
export default ClassList;
```

What's happening to me is that "hello, test 1, test 2" from classlist.js is being displayed under "filler text" in experience.js. How do I get classlist.js to open as a new page? (For reference I do have classlist imported as well as Router, Route, and Link).

Answer (score 1):

In that case,you need to place **ClassList** and **Experience** component on same level

```
<Route exact path="/experience" component={Experience}/>
<Route exact path="/classlist" component={ClassList}/>
```

Now you dont get **Experience** component content while loading **ClassList** component